# How to create new clone instance of PSObject object

Tags: powershell

I want to create new instance of my custom PSObject. I have a Button object created as PSObject and I want to create new object Button2 which has the same members as Button does, but I can't find a way how to clone the original object without making it referenced in original object (if I change a property in Button2 it changes in Button as well). Is there a way how to do it similarly as with hashtables and arrays via some Clone() method?

Comment: You did not specify if the clone should be shallow or not, which is critical (and the answers below differ in this behavior) - https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed there is no clone method! However where there is a will...

```
$o = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ prop1='a' ; prop2='b' }
$o2 = New-Object PsObject
$o.psobject.properties | % {
    $o2 | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
}
$o.prop1 = 'newvalue'

$o
$o2
```

Output:

```
prop2     prop1                                                                 
-----     -----                                                                 
b         newvalue                                                              
b         a
```

Comment: That's weird, I don't have Clone method available. Looks like there is a problem in the way I crate the object. When I use your example I have Clone method available, but I create empty object first and then add all members via Add-Member. So when I use:
$object = New-Object PSObject
$object | Add-Member NoteProperty propVal "test"
powershell says that [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] doesn't contain method Close.

Comment: @JosefNemec My bad I used the wrong syntax to create the PsObject. You are correct that there is no clone method. So to work around that you can just copy all the originals properties to the new object.

Comment: Doesnt work if you have objects as properties, then those objects are references so editing it edits the clone as well as the original

Comment: Add-Member is very slow !

Comment: Note that this copy would be shallow (https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c)

Answer (score 88):

Easiest way is to use the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.copy.aspx) Method of a `PsObject` ==> `$o2 = $o1.PsObject.Copy()`

```
$o1 = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
    Fld1 = 'Fld1';
    Fld2 = 'Fld2';
    Fld3 = 'Fld3'}

$o2 = $o1.PsObject.Copy()

$o2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Fld4 -Value 'Fld4'
$o2.Fld1 = 'Changed_Fld'

$o1 | Format-List
$o2 | Format-List
```

Output:

```
Fld3 : Fld3
Fld2 : Fld2
Fld1 : Fld1

Fld3 : Fld3
Fld2 : Fld2
Fld1 : Changed_Fld
Fld4 : Fld4
```

Comment: Note that this will do a shallow copy only.

Comment: Just to expand the understanding of RB's comment 
https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c

Answer (score 23):

For some reason PSObject.Copy() doesn't work for all object types. Another solution to create a copy of an object is to convert it to/from Json then save it in a new variable:

```
$CustomObject1 = [pscustomobject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
$CustomObject2 = $CustomObject1 | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json
$CustomObject2 | add-Member -Name "e" -Value "5" -MemberType noteproperty

$CustomObject1 | Format-List
$CustomObject2 | Format-List
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that will deep clone a psobject that contains other psobjects.

Comment: Note due to a bug, in some versions of powershell you need to use `ConvertTo-Json -compress -depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json` (note the `-compress`) if the data has linebreaks anywhere in it (it's possible other characters trigger this to)

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility:

```
 $o1 = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ prop1='a' ; prop2='b' }
 $o2 = $o1 | select *
 $o2.prop1 = 'newvalue'
 $o1.prop1
 $o2.prop1
 a
 newvalue
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... I got newvalue for both. Try calling `GetHashCode()`, they are pointing to the same object for me.

Comment: Different method.  Works better.

Comment: Nice approach using `Select-Object`.

Comment: Knew there had to be a better way than creating a new object a property at a time.

Comment: I think `Select-Object` does the same thing internally. Dynamic property creation. Definitely less code to type though with this approach.

Comment: Note that this copy would be shallow (https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [pscustomobject] example with the hidden .psobject.copy():

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{message='hi'}
$a.message
hi

$b = $a.psobject.copy()
$b.message
hi

$a.message = 'there'
$a.message
there

$b.message
hi
```

Answer (score 5):

The Better way i found out was to use ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json.
Ee -
Suppose you want to clone a object $toBeClonedObject, just run below code to clone.

```bsh
$clonedObject = $toBeClonedObject | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of TeraFlux's answer below and is susceptible to the same issues: Default depth for ConvertTo-Json is 2 (not very useful for a deep clone) and it breaks if any of the values contain Linebreaks

Answer (score 4):

Starting from PowerShell v5, you can use Class.
The problem with psobject.Copy() is, if you update the cloned object, then your template object's referenced properties will be also updated.

example:

```
function testTemplates
{
    $PSCustomObjectTemplate = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        List1 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@()  # will be updated in template
        String1 = "value1" # will not be updated in template
        Bool1 = $false # will not be updated in template
    }

    $objectFromPSTemplate1 = $PSCustomObjectTemplate.psobject.Copy()
    $objectFromPSTemplate1.List1.Add("Value")
    $objectFromPSTemplate1.String1 = "value2" 
    $objectFromPSTemplate.Bool1 = $true 

    # $PSCustomObjectTemplate IS updated, so CANNOT be used as a clean template!
    $PSCustomObjectTemplate

    Class ClassTemplate {
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$List1 = @() # will not be updated in template
        [string]$String1 = "value1" # will not be updated in template
        [bool]$Bool1 = $false # will not be updated in template
    }
    $objectFromClassTemplate = [ClassTemplate]::new()
    $objectFromClassTemplate.List1.Add("Value")
    $objectFromClassTemplate.String1 = "value2"
    $objectFromClassTemplate.Bool1 = $true

    # $ClassTemplate IS NOT updated, so can be used as a clean template!
    [ClassTemplate]::new()
}
```

testTemplates

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> testTemplates

List1   String1 Bool1
-----   ------- -----
{Value} value1  False
```

**-> Template from PSCustomObject is updated (referenced property -List1)**

```
List1   String1 Bool1
-----   ------- -----
{}      value1  False
```

**-> Template from Class is safe**

Answer (score 2):

This usually works for me:

```
$Source = [PSCustomObject]@{ Value = 'Test' };
$Copy = ($Source | ConvertTo-Json) | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version using Clixml

```
function Get-PSObjectClone {
  param ( [psobject] $InputObject )
  $_temp = New-TemporaryFile
  $InputObject | Export-Clixml -Path $_temp -Depth 100
  $_object = Import-Clixml -Path $_temp
  Remove-Item $_temp -Force
  Write-Output $_object
}
```

Works with everything I've thrown at it

EDIT: I've actually come up with a much cleaner version that seems to work flawlessly.

```
[Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize( [Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize( $InputObject ))
```

Comment: Doesnt work good with ScriptBlock :`Deserialize(Serialize({Write-Host 1}))` returns string type

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a Utility class or define it in your current section

```
function clone($obj)
{
    $newobj = New-Object PsObject
    $obj.psobject.Properties | % {Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -InputObject $newobj -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value}
    return $newobj
}
```

Usage:

`$clonedobj = clone $obj`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @TeraFlux, here's a function that will do a deep copy on multiple objects and accepts pipeline input.

Note, it leverages json conversion with a default depth of 100, which lends it to a few weaknesses

- It's going to be slow on deep or complex objects, or objects with expensive (slow) pseudoproperties ([methods](https://www.quora.com/How-could-you-explain-what-is-a-Method-in-programming) pretending to be properties that are calculated on the fly when asked for)

  - Though it should still be faster than the Add-Member approach because the heavy lifting is going through a compiled function
- Anything that can't be stored in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types_and_syntax) may get corrupted or left behind (methods will be a prime candidate for this type of error)

  - Though any object that can safely go through this process should be savable, able to be safely stored (for recovery) or exported for transportation

I would be interested in any caveats or improvements to deal with these

```
function Clone-Object {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [object[]]$objects,
        [Parameter()] [int] $depth = 100
    )
    $clones = foreach( $object in $objects ){
        $object `
        | ConvertTo-Json `
            -Compress `
            -depth $depth `
        | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    return $clones
}
```

Here are some very basic unit tests

```
$testClone = {
    $test1 = $null
    $test2 = $null
    $test3 = $null

    $Test1 = [psCustomObject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
    $Test2 = $Test1 | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json
    $Test2 | add-Member -Name "e" -Value "5" -MemberType noteproperty
    $Test3 = $test2 | Clone-Object
    $Test3 | add-Member -Name "f" -Value "6" -MemberType noteproperty
    $Test1.a = 7
    $Test2.a = 8

    #$Expected0 = [psCustomObject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
    $Expected1 = [pscustomobject]@{a=7; b=2; c=3; d=4}
    $Expected2 = [pscustomobject]@{a=8; b=2; c=3; d=4; e=5}
    $Expected3 = [pscustomobject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4; e=5; f=6}

    $results1 = @(); $results1+=$test1; $results1+=$expected1
    $results2 = @(); $results2+=$test2; $results2+=$expected2
    $results3 = @(); $results3+=$test3; $results3+=$expected3
    $results1 | Format-Table # if these don't match then its probably passing references (copy not clone)
    $results2 | Format-Table # if these don't match the core approach is incorrect
    $results3 | Format-Table # if these don't match the function didn't work

}
&$testClone
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
function Copy-Object($Object) {
    $copy = @()
    $Object.ForEach({
        $currentObject = $_
        $currentObjectCopy = New-Object $currentObject.GetType().Name
        $currentObjectCopy.psobject.Properties.ForEach({
            $_.Value = $currentObject.psobject.Properties[($_.Name)].Value
        })
        $copy += $currentObjectCopy
    })
    return $copy
}
```

Test objects:

```
class TestObjectA {
    [string]$g
    [int[]]$h
    
    [string]getJ(){
        return 'j'
    }
}

class TestObjectB {
    [string]$a
    [int]$b
    [hashtable]$c
    [TestObjectA[]]$d

    [string]getI(){
        return 'i'
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
$b = New-Object -TypeName TestObjectB -Property @{
    a = 'value a'
    b = 2
    c = @{ e = 'value e'; f = 3 }
    d = New-Object -TypeName TestObjectA -Property @{
        g = 'value g'
        h = @(4,5,6)
    }
}

$bCopy = Copy-Object $b

# test with simple comparison
-not $(Compare-Object $b $bCopy)
True

# test json deep conversion output
$bJson = $b | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$bCopyJson = $bCopy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
-not $(Compare-Object $bJson $bCopyJson)
True

# test methods are intact
$bCopy.getI()
i
$bCopy.d.GetJ()
j    

# test objects are seperate instances
$bCopy.b = 3
$b.b
2
$bCopy.b
3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since `Select-Object -Property` expands wildcards in property names, a simple way to **shallow**-clone is this:

```
# Set up object
$o1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Fld1 = 'Fld1';
    Fld2 = 'Fld2';
    Fld3 = 'Fld3'}

# Clone
$o2 = $o1 | Select-Object -Property *;

# Tests
$o1 -eq $o2;
$o1 | Format-List;
$o2 | Format-List;
```