# Using intermediate variable to work with array (reference type)

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to use `$a` variable in this script for working with intermediate steps so that I don't have to use `$array[$array.Count-1]` repeatedly. Similarly for `$prop` as well . However, values are being overwritten by last value in loop.

```
$guests = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\shant_000\Desktop\UploadGuest_test.csv
$output = gc '.\Sample Json.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

foreach ($g in $guests) {
    $array.Add($output);
    $a = $array[$array.Count-1];

    $a.Username = $g.'EmailAddress';
    $a.DisplayName = $g.'FirstName' + ' ' + $g.'LastName';
    $a.Password = $g.'LastName' + '123';
    $a.Email = $g.'EmailAddress';

    foreach ($i in $a.ProfileProperties.Count) {
        $j = $i - 1;

        $prop = $a.ProfileProperties[$j];

        if ($prop.PropertyName -eq "FirstName") {
            $prop.PropertyValue = $g.'FirstName';
        } elseif ($prop.PropertyName -eq "LastName") {
            $prop.PropertyValue = $g.'LastName';
        }

        $a.ProfileProperties[$j] = $prop;
    }

    $array[$array.Count-1] = $a;
}

$array;
```

Comment: `$output = gc '.\Sample Json.json' | ConvertFrom-Json` -> `$outputJson = gc '.\Sample Json.json'`, `$array.Add($output)` -> `[void]$array.Add(($outputJson | ConvertFrom-Json))`

Answer (score 0):

All array elements are referencing one actual variable: `$output`.

Create an entirely new object each time by repeating JSON-parsing:

```
$jsontext = gc '.\Sample Json.json'
..........
foreach ($g in $guests) {
    $a = $jsontext | ConvertFrom-Json

    # process $a
    # ............

    $array.Add($a) >$null
}
```

In case the JSON file is very big and you change only a few parts of it you can use a faster cloning technique on the changed parts (and their entire parent chain) via `.PSObject.Copy()`:

```
foreach ($g in $guests) {
    $a = $output.PSObject.Copy()
    # ............

    $a.ProfileProperties = $a.ProfileProperties.PSObject.Copy()
    # ............
    foreach ($i in $a.ProfileProperties.Count) {
        # ............
        $prop = $a.ProfileProperties[$j].PSObject.Copy();
        # ............
    }

    $array.Add($a) >$null
}
```

Comment: See also: [In Powershell, how to store an object in array, by "value" and not by "reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18036823)

Comment: Are you sure that `.PSObject.Copy()` will make deep enough clone in OP case?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, appending `$object` appends a references to the same single object, so you keep changing the values for all elements in the list. Unfortunately the approach [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682703/1630171) suggested (which I thought would work at first too) doesn't work if your JSON datastructure has nested objects, because `Copy()` only clones the topmost object while the nested objects remain references to their original.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $o = '{"foo":{"bar":42},"baz":23}' | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\> $o | Format-Custom *

class PSCustomObject
{
  foo =
    class PSCustomObject
    {
      bar = 42
    }
  baz = 23
}

PS C:\> $o1 = $o
PS C:\> $o2 = $o.PSObject.Copy()
```

If you change the nested property `bar` on both `$o1` and `$o2` it has on both objects the value that was last set to any of them:

```
PS C:\> $o1.foo.bar = 23
PS C:\> $o2.foo.bar = 24
PS C:\> $o1.foo.bar
24
PS C:\> $o2.foo.bar
24
```

Only if you change a property of the topmost object you'll get a difference between `$o1` and `$o2`:

```
PS C:\> $o1.baz = 5
PS C:\> $o.baz
5
PS C:\> $o1.baz
5
PS C:\> $o2.baz
23
```

While you could do a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9204829/1630171) it's not as simple and straightforward as one would like to think. Usually it takes less effort (and simpler code) to just create the object multiple times as [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680400/using-intermediate-variable-in-powershell-to-work-with-array-reference-type#comment64740736_38680400) suggested in the comments to your question.

I'd also recommend to avoid appending to an array (or arraylist) in a loop. You can simply echo your objects inside the loop and collect the entire output as a list/array by assigning the loop to a variable:

```
$json = Get-Content '.\Sample Json.json' -Raw
$array = foreach ($g in $guests) {
    $a = $json | ConvertFrom-Json   # create new object

    $a.Username = $g.'EmailAddress'
    ...

    $a   # echo object, so it can be collected in $array
}
```

Use `Get-Content -Raw` on PowerShell v3 and newer (or `Get-Content | Out-String` on earlier versions) to avoid issues with multiline JSON data in the JSON file.