# Defining a powershell variable from a CSV that can be edited independently

Tags: powershell, csv, variables

I have used Import-Csv in Powershell 4.0 to import a CSV with the intention of adding duplicate rows with variations. Let's say that $data is a variable containing the CSV, this is my output when I print it:-

```
PS C:> $data

Var1           Var2           Var3           Var4                                          

----           ----           ----           ----                                          

Ans1           Ans2           Ans3           Ans4
```

I then create a duplicate of the row:-

```
PS C:>$firstRow = $data[0]
```

In theory, I would amend $firstRow and add it back in as a new line:-

```
$firstRow.Var1 = 'TEST'
```

This is where it gets interesting. Amending the variable as I did above also amends the original variable:-

```
PS C:> $data

Var1           Var2           Var3           Var4                                          

----           ----           ----           ----                                          

TEST           Ans2           Ans3           Ans4
```

A google search didn't really shed any light on this. I also noticed that this doesn't happen when the variables are standard variables (e.g. String, Integer etc).

Does anybody know of a workaround for this issue? Or if there's a reason why this happens in this specific case?

Kind Regards,
Ben

Comment: This is how arrays work in .NET - `$firstRow` really holds a reference to the same object as `$data[0]` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is not very efficient at accomplishing what you want, but it will work.

```
$firstRow = new-object psobject
$data[0].psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {
    $firstRow | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
}
$firstRow.Var1 = 'TEST'
```

Basically it just loops property by property and clones the first row of `$data` to `$firstRow`

Reference: [How to create new clone instance of PSObject object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581568/how-to-create-new-clone-instance-of-psobject-object)

**EDIT** Thanks to TheMadTechnician, the psobject Copy method CAN be used in this scenario

```
$firstRow = $data[0].psobject.Copy()
$firstRow.Var1 = 'TEST'
```

Comment: The most upvoted answer in that link does work. You can do `$firstRow = $data[0].psobject.copy()` and it works just fine.

Comment: oh, I was doing `$data[0].copy()` ha ha I will update my answer then!

Comment: This really does clear things up thanks! So just to clarify, the best way to achieve it is to create a new object which is a duplicate or the original object?

Comment: @BenRoberts Yeah, since by default pwershell just assigns by reference when it comes to objects