# Array with PSCustomObjects changes values even if not called

Tags: powershell, scope

I wrote a script (PowerShell ≥ 3) that basically looks for certain files, then checks if their name is already used in the path where the files later should get copied to and if so, it adds `_OutCopy` to the name. <sub>It does more than that, but that is of no concern for this question.</sub>

```cs
#requires -version 3

Function Start-FileSearch(){
    param(
        [string]$InputPath = $(throw 'InputPath not set'),
        [string]$Format = $(throw 'Format not set')
    )
    $InFiles = @()
    $InFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $InputPath -Filter $Format -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            InFullName = $_.FullName
            OutName = "ZYX"
        }
    })
    return $InFiles
}

Function Start-OverwriteProtection(){
    param(
        [string]$OutputPath = $(throw 'OutputPath not set'),
        [array]$InFiles = $(throw 'InFiles not set')
    )

    $NewFiles = $InFiles

    for($i=0; $i -lt $NewFiles.Length; $i++){
        $NewFiles[$i].OutName = "$($NewFiles[$i].OutName)_OutCopy"  # this, of course, is simplified. 
    }
    return $NewFiles
}

Function Start-AllStuff() {
    $InFiles = @(Start-FileSearch -InputPath "D:\Temp\In_Test" -Format "*.jpg")
    $InFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property OutName,InFullName | Out-Host

    $NewFiles = @(Start-OverwriteProtection -OutputPath "D:\Temp" -InFiles $InFiles)
    $InFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property OutName,InFullName | Out-Host
    $NewFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property OutName,InFullName | Out-Host
}

Start-AllStuff
```

Clearly, the second `$InFiles | Format-Table` should also output `"ZYX"` for `.OutName` - however, it includes the already changed values.

What I tried:

- Putting all variables in `private:`-scope,
- Putting the commands inside/outside a third function `Start-Allstuff()`,
- Renaming the variables for each use case (i.e. use `$InFiles` all along) / not renaming the variables (i.e. as shown above, with `$NewFiles`).
- Calling the variables after their creation (i.e. `$InFiles = @(Start-FileSearch`[...]`); $InFiles`)

Nothing helps.

My understanding, as of now, was that it is impossible for a variable to change when not called directly. (E.g. `$InFiles = $OutFiles` should change the variable on the left, not the one on the right.)

#### What am I missing here?

<sub>For everyone that wonders: Yes, I dug further into the problems of my [previous question ("Compare-Object does not work with PSCustomObjects from another script")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060841) and found that this is must be the reason why it won't work - at least it is one of the reasons.</sub>

Comment: In PowerShell (and most other programming languages), if you assign an **object** to a variable, only the reference is copied (and not all it's properties). To clone a PowerShell object, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581568/how-to-create-new-clone-instance-of-psobject-object

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe line 27 is completing the action when line 36 is run, giving you the completed result in the 2nd $InFiles

Comment: Glad to see the scope of this question reduced in overhead. Should make it easier to diagnose what is going on here.

Comment: @Matt Agreed. I worked on false presumtpions, which lead to this bloated scenario. My bad - I'm sorry for stealing more time than I should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iRon was correct, you need to make a clone of the PSObject, code below.

```
$NewFiles = $InFiles
$NewInFiles = $InFiles | select *

for($i=0; $i -lt $NewFiles.Length; $i++){
.........................
$NewFiles = @(Start-OverwriteProtection -OutputPath "D:\" -InFiles $InFiles)
$NewInFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property OutName,InFullName | Out-Host
$NewFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property OutName,InFullName | Out-Host
```

Looks like your for loop was modifying the $InFiles, check out my results. Tested with random images.

[image: $Infiles outside For loop]

[image: $Infiles inside For loop]

Comment: A small note: copying an array by doing `$NewInFiles = $InFiles | select *` is slow (which may not matter in this case but it also can change the types of the objects.) A (much as in 100x) faster alternative is to do `$NewInFiles = @() + $InFiles`. This works because, when doing concatenation, PowerShell copies the arguments to `+` into a new array.

Comment: @BrucePayette Sorry to say so, but for me, **this does not work** with my script (replaced Drew's `$InFiles | Select *` with `@() + $InFiles`.)

Comment: Right - it copies the collection but doesn't clone the objects. Since you are mutating the objects, Drew's solution is more appropriate in this case.