# Is there a spread operator equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In JavaScript you can use the spread operator to clone an object and then extend its properties. Is there an equivalent operation in powershell to accomplish this?

JS example:

```js
const b = {
  ...a,
  newProp: 'abc'
}
```

Comment: The answer is no. You can copy the object (shallow copy) and then just add the property -> `$newobject = $obj.psobject.copy() | add-member -NotePropertyMembers @{newprop = 2} -PassThru`. You could also use `Select-Object` calculated properties -> `$obj | select *,@{n='newprop';e={'abc'}}`. Arrays or lists in powershell automatically enumerate when called and when piped each element is pushed through the pipeline separately. In powershell, you have to use extra code to stop the enumeration rather than extra code to force the enumeration.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know wbout the .Copy() method under PSObject.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various discussions on StackOverflow (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581568/how-to-create-new-clone-instance-of-psobject-object)) about cloning objects.  I've not revisited them in a while, however absent a `.Clone()` method on the object itself these approaches often seem to only clone shallow.  Meaning deeply nested properties, and more complex properties like arrays and/or other objects aren't easily cloned.  It is however easy to extend objects in PowerShell.  `Select-Object` has such a capability through use of [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1). `Select-Object` will output a new object of type `[PSCustomObject]`.  You can use `Add-Member` to add properties while maintaining the formal typing of the original object, however this add to the object it's passed, you may have to play around to achieve the cloning aspect of your question.

[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1)

[Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1)

Possible Example:

```
# Get an object to work with:
$OriginalObject = (Get-Process)[0]

$NewObject = 
$OriginalObject | 
Select-Object *,@{Name = 'Date'; Expression = { Get-Date } }
```

This adds a date property the value of which is the result of the expression.  Admittedly not that useful here, but it's just to demonstrate the point.  The `*` carries forward the existing properties resulting in something close to a clone of the original plus the new property.  You can put anything you want in the expression and add as many properties as you want.  So you can see there's a lot of utility behind calculated properties.  You can also tailor the object further by naming actual properties of the source object instead of the wildcard (`*`).

Comment: `$new = $old |Select-Object *,@{...}` is probably to closest we'll get to `...` in PowerShell :-)

Comment: Not bad. I'll take it!