What is the difference between $null and the empty output of Where-Object?
Consider the following:
$psversiontable # 7.4.6

$a = $null
$null -eq $a # Returns $true
$a.GetType() # You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
$b = $a.PSObject.Copy() # You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

$c = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "oiawmij3209j23oifnoeicn" } # Matches nothing, should return nothing
$null -eq $c # Returns $true
$c.GetType() # You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
$d = $c.PSObject.Copy() # Works
$d.GetType() # PSCustomObject

My questions:

What is the difference between $a and $c in this situation? They both apparently equate to $null.
Why does $c.PSObject.Copy() work when $a.PSObject.Copy() doesn't?
Why does $c.PSObject.Copy() work when $c.GetType() doesn't?
What causes this? Is it something to do with Where-Object, or to do with PSObject.Copy(), or something else?
How can I/should I reliably differentiate between/test for these cases?

Thanks for your time.
Edit: a comment asked why I'm using the PSObject property. It's to avoid this problem:
# $hash2 is a "copy" of $hash1, but both variables actually just contain references to the same object in memory, so modifying $hash2 also modifies $hash1
$hash1 = @{ foo = "apple" }
$hash2 = $hash1
$hash2.bar = "banana"
Write-Host $hash1.bar # Returns "banana"

# $hash4 is a "real" copy of $hash3, i.e. each variable contains a reference to a different object in memory, thus modifying $hash4 does NOT also modify $hash3
$hash3 = @{ foo = "apple" }
$hash4 = $hash3.PSObject.Copy()
$hash4.bar = "banana"
Write-Host $hash3.bar # Returns nothing

In the relevant production code there may be better ways to work around this, but that's how I'm currently doing it, and what spawned the question.

A pipeline that has no results (as e.g.:... | Where-Object { $False }, yields an enumerable null. I think your questions are already covered by this document Everything you wanted to know about $null.

Normally a PowerShell user doesn't need the hidden PSObject property or differentiate between a $null and an enumerable null, so please explane (in the question) why you are in need to differentiate between them.

what you get from a scriptblock that doesnt produce a output is [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value. The value is an empty PSObject. The reason .GetType() work is because of the logic used for .Copy() which creates a [psobject]::new()

In short: In addition to $null, PowerShell has a special value called the enumerable null aka "Automation Null" (the [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value singleton), which represent the absence of output from a command. In expressions, it behaves the same as $null, but it acts differently in enumeration contexts such as the pipeline, where it acts like an empty collection and therefore enumerates nothing.
See the linked duplicate for details.

You can detect an enumerable null with $null -eq $value -and $value -is [psobject].
A green-lit, but as yet (as of PowerShell 7.5.0) unimplemented enhancement will allow simplifying this test to $value -is [System.Management.Automation.Null] in the future. See the second linked duplicate for details.

$c.GetType() doesn't work,  because - due to treating the enumerable like $null in an expression - your call is in effect the same as $null.GetType(). That you can access the intrinsic .psobject property on the enumerable null ($c) (but not on $null ($a)) is arguably a bug, a leaky implementation that reveals the fact that the enumerable null is technically an object (of type [psobject] aka [System.Management.Automation.PSObject], namely the aforementioned [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value singleton)

@iRon I updated the question with an explanation of why I'm using PSObject.Copy(). As noted, there may be better ways to solve the issue, but this is what precipitated the conditions that led to this question.

@mklement0 Thanks. Your various comments (both here and in response to @sirtao), along with the posed duplicates thoroughly answer the question. I have been vaguely aware of the automation null, but have never actually run into it like this. Should you wish to compile the points into an answer I would mark it as the answer, though I'm not sure how questions closed as dupes work, or what the convention is for them.

Glad to hear it, @mmseng. I think the linked duplicates in combination with the comments here probably provide sufficient guidance to future readers.

@mklement0, I have voted to reopen the question (even I have no intention to answer it myself) because "The fact that the enumerable null (which you can most succinctly create with & {}) even surfaces as an object in PowerShell code (enabling things like (& {}).psobject and (& {}) -is [psobject] is arguably a bug (a leaky implementation of an abstraction)." might require to uniquely answer through a formal answer rather than multiple comments.

With respect to using the PSObject: as said, you don't need the PSObject property for the example you give as you might simply use the Clone() method instead on the hashtable itself: $hash2 = $hash1.Clone(). Note that both methods actually make shallow copy:  $hash3 = @{ foo = @{ bar = 'apple' } }; $hash4 = $hash3.PSObject.Copy(); $hash4.foo.bar = 'Banana'; $hash3.foo.bar --> Banana.

@iRon I was aware of the shallowness; it didn't happen to be relevant in the production code. Not sure why I neglected the .clone() method, but my old notes reference a @mklement0 answer warning against it just because it's up to the specific type whether the clone() implementation is shallow or deep, or even whether to implement it at all. I likely went with .psobject.copy() as mklement0 implied that the copy is "reliably" shallow. However they also warned against using it on types other than [pscustomobject], which I failed to note.

P.S. FWIW, the .psobject.copy() method is also bandied around a lot in some other answers without near as much careful context given. e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581568/how-to-create-new-clone-instance-of-psobject-object

I went ahead and collected all of the relevant details into an actual answer, since the question was reopened. Feel free to edit/provide corrections. I also wanted to re-capture the duplicates that were originally linked when the question was closed.

This question was originally (and reasonably) closed as a duplicate of the following questions:

Why is an empty PowerShell pipeline not the same as null?
Why is piping null to set-variable causing different outcomes?

However @mklement0 and others provide a lot of details in comments in this question which deserve to be captured in a more visible and collected answer, though they may be repeated somewhat in mklement0's answers to the other questions. As I (OP) am the learner in this situation, feel free to edit the answer/provide corrections.
The core of this question (and the linked duplicates) revolves around the technical differences between $null and "automation null" ([System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value), a.k.a. "the enumerable null".
To answer the direct questions in the OP:

What is the difference between $a and $c in this situation?

$a is $null, while $c is automation null. Automation null is returned via a pipeline that has no results, which can be  achieved in different ways, as demonstrated by the different questions:

Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "oiawmij3209j23oifnoeicn" }
1,2,3,4 | ? { $_ -ge 5 }
& { }




Why does $c.PSObject.Copy() work when $a.PSObject.Copy() doesn't?

Because $c, as automation null is technically a [PSObject] with a PSObject property, while $a is just $null.
However the fact that $c.PSObject can be accessed is arguably a bug, see further context below.


Why does $c.PSObject.Copy() work when $c.GetType() doesn't?

In the former context you are simply accessing an existing property of $c.
The latter context is an expression, where $c is effectively being evaluated to $null, and is thus equivalent to $null.GetType().


What causes this? Is it something to do with Where-Object, or to do with PSObject.Copy(), or something else?

As noted, automation null is being returned by the pipeline where Where-Object returns no results.


How can I/should I reliably differentiate between/test for these cases?

In the current implementation, automation null is exposed as a [PSObject], and so detecting it, and differentiating it from $null can be achieved with ($null -eq $value) -and ($value -is [PSObject]).
Alternatively, you can probe the enumerability like so: ($null -eq $value) -and (@($value).length -eq 0), or ($null -eq $value) -and (@($value).count -eq 0).

The length/count of an array containing automation null will be 0, while that of @($null) will be 1 (for reasons someone more experienced would have to explain).


However see below about potential future improvements, which would presumably break one or both of these detection methods.



Further context:

Currently, automation null behaves as $null in expressions, but acts differently in enumeration contexts such as the pipeline, where it acts like an empty collection and therefore enumerates nothing.
The fact that the enumerable null even surfaces as an object in PowerShell code - enabling things like (& {}).psobject and (& {}) -is [psobject] - is arguably a bug; a leaky implementation of an abstraction which reveals the fact that it is technically an object (of type [psobject] a.k.a. [System.Management.Automation.PSObject], namely the aforementioned [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value singleton).
A green-lit enhancement that has yet to be implemented (as of PowerShell 7.5.0) will enable a conceptually appropriate test for whether a given value is the enumerable null: $value -is [System.Management.Automation.Null].
As noted, see the duplicates linked above for more detail in mklement0's various answers.


EDIT: imprecise answer, read related comments for clarifications.
Original answer for context:
Powershell does a lot of hidden work.
In this case, Where-Object returns not a $null but a [System.Object.PSCustomObject] with a empty(=$null) value.
But Powershell likes its automatic unpacking so when compared it automagically and transparently to the user unpacks the object to its value... which is $null.
But it's still an object!
You can also see this difference in VSCode's debug: $a has a value of $null but $c is shown having subvalues, but empty.

It's (nowadays) called the enumerable null, and it is an instance of type [psobject] aka [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]; specifically, it is a singleton returned by [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value. While it is true that this singleton has no properties, it does not have a $null value. There is no unpacking happening. The value is a PowerShell-internal magic value that is treated like $null in expressions vs. like an empty enumerable in enumeration contexts such as the pipeline.

The fact that the enumerable null (which you can most succinctly create with & {}) even surfaces as an object in PowerShell code (enabling things like (& {}).psobject and (& {}) -is [psobject] is arguably a bug (a leaky implementation of an abstraction).  A green-lit enhancement that has yet to be implemented (as of PowerShell 7.5.0) will enable a conceptually appropriate test for whether a given value is the enumerable null, $value -is [System.Management.Automation.Null]
